# Formatting error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'

Tags: java, formatting

I'm trying to get each variable to print out with two decimal places but I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

```
System.out.printf("%.2",custNum + "\t" + beginBal + " \t " + financeCharge + "\t\t" +
                          purchases + " \t  " + payments + "\t\t" + endBal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format `String` should be `%.2f` and one for each term. Something like,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f%n", custNum, beginBal, 
        financeCharge, purchases, payments, endBal);
```